# What is a single word which could mean that I am "annoyingly proud" of something

Tags: single-word-requests

Let me explain, I have an apartment with a great view; I cant help but bring it up in every conversation and every time someone inquires about how life was in Trivandrum. I could excuse myself saying, I was annoyingly proud of my balcony view.

Comment: In some parts of the US it would be said you're about to bust your buttons (the implication being that you're swelling your chest out with pride so much).

Comment: @HotLicks Wouldn't that be a case for men only..swelling your "chest"?

Comment: @JonyAgarwal - To my knowledge the term is asexual.

Answer (score 4):

> I was **boastful** about my balcony view

Alternatively...

> I was **smug** about my balcony view

> [smug](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/smug): Exhibiting or feeling great or offensive satisfaction with oneself or with one's situation; self-righteously complacent:
>   [boast](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/boastful): 2. A source of pride.
>   **boastful** (adj) tending to boast; characterized by boasting
>   <sub>Source: The Free Dictionary</sub>

Answer (score 2):

This is not a single word as requested, but an appropriate phrase is:

> "I could **gush for hours** about my balcony view."

Answer (score 2):

*I **think the sun shines out my ass** (or butt, backside, etc.)/outta me anytime I speak about my balcony view* [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=think+the+sun+shines+out&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthink%20the%20sun%20shines%20out%3B%2Cc0)

> **think the sun shines out backside**
>
> To believe a person is better or more important than others or above
> reproach. Various slang and vulgar synonyms for "backside" are often substituted. (Note: If thought about oneself, it means that he or she is
> arrogant, conceited, or self-absorbed. If someone thinks this of
> another person, it means that he or she loves or admires that person
> to such a degree as to be blind to any of their potential faults.) Tom
> has acted like he's such a hotshot after getting the promotion. *He
> thinks the sun shines out his backside! He's absolutely
> head-over-heels in love with Mary. Even though I find her a bit
> irritating, he thinks the sun shines out her backside.* [Farlex Dictionary of Idioms](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/sun)

Comment: Reminds me of a similar French expression: “**[Péter plus haut que son cul](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-anglais/p%C3%A9ter%20plus%20haut%20que%20son%20cul)**) = “fart higher than one's arse” (literally) = “to believe that your s*** don’t stink”/that you’re hot s***/that you’re better than the rest/etc +1 for the imagery, multi-worded as it is!

Answer (score 1):

Many things become annoying when they exist or are done in excess.  Excessive pride and being excessively proud are examples of this and there’s even a single-word adjective for it:

“**[Overproud](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/overproud)**” = “Excessively proud.” (from The Free Dictionary by Farlex)

Answer (score 0):

A few choices would work:

> **swollen-headed**, **big-headed** or **puffed-up**.

These all mean 'full of yourself'.

> **Conceited** or **vain**

also work:

> con·ceit·ed  (kən-sē′tĭd) adj.
>   Holding or characterized by an unduly high opinion of oneself; vain.

[conceited. (n.d.) American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition. (2011). Retrieved November 18 2015 from http://www.thefreedictionary.com/conceited]

For your example,

> I am **swollen-headed** | **big-headed** | **puffed-up** | **conceited** | **vain** about my balcony view.

Answer (score 0):

Possible adjectives: fervent/fervid, ardent, effusive, gushing, zealous, rhapsodic

Possible verbs:  vaunt, crow, gush, rhapsodize